# DecodeStream error with Facebook Graph Request

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi i have implemented Facebook login into my app and am now trying to download the users profile picture and pass it into a RoundedImageView
However i am encountering an error when it test it and there is no image showing, the error is:

```
skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

I am also getting these two errors directly before it

```
ReadStreamToBuffer : Qmage Stream read error!! required length 12 bytes, but red 0 bytes
isQmage : input SkStreamRewindable length is less than Qmage minimum size : 0
```

Here is my main asynctask for downloading and setting the image

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String userId = urls[0];
        Bitmap bmp = null;

            try {
                URL image_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+ userId + "/picture?type=large");
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error", "image download error");
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return bmp;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);

    }
}
```

And here is how i call it

```
final RoundedImageView profilePic = (RoundedImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myProfilePic);
    new DownloadImageTask(profilePic).execute(userId);
```

Thanks for any and all help

Comment: Can you please try to replicate it in graph api explorer using your access token? If you can get the picture there, then it would be code problem.https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/